# Fire a RowCommand event from ImageButton created dynamically inside ITemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, rowcommand

I have a dynamically created GirdView based on value of a DropDownList.
I use the ITemplate interface to generate the fields:

```
public class CreateItemTemplateOrder : ITemplate
{
     ImageButton imgbtn_up;
     ImageButton imgbtn_down;

     string s_imgbtn_up_name;
     string s_imgbtn_up_ImageUrl;
     string s_imgbtn_up_CommandName;
     string s_imgbtn_up_CommandArgument;

     public CreateItemTemplateOrder(string imgbtn_up_name, string imgbtn_up_ImageUrl, string imgbtn_up_CommandName, string imgbtn_up_CommandArgument)
     {

         this.s_imgbtn_up_name = imgbtn_up_name;
         this.s_imgbtn_up_ImageUrl = imgbtn_up_ImageUrl;
         this.s_imgbtn_up_CommandName = imgbtn_up_CommandName;
         this.s_imgbtn_up_CommandArgument = imgbtn_up_CommandArgument;

     }

     public void InstantiateIn(Control objContainer)
     {
         imgbtn_up = new ImageButton();
         imgbtn_up.DataBinding += new EventHandler(imgbtn_up_DataBinding);
         objContainer.Controls.Add(imgbtn_up);
     }

     private void imgbtn_up_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         ImageButton imgbtn_up = (ImageButton)sender;
         imgbtn_up.ID = s_imgbtn_up_name;
         imgbtn_up.ImageUrl = s_imgbtn_up_ImageUrl;
         imgbtn_up.CommandName = s_imgbtn_up_CommandName;
         imgbtn_up.CommandArgument = s_imgbtn_up_CommandArgument;
         imgbtn_up.CausesValidation = false;
     }
 }
```

Now I want to fire RowCommand From this dynamically generated column with command argument and command name bounded to this ImageButton

the code to get this working is:

```
 Protected void inizializza_gw_tipi(){
       TemplateField order_col = new TemplateField;
       order_col.ItemTemplate = new CreateItemTemplateOrdine("imgbtn_up", "~/imgs/Up.gif", "minus", "order");
       order_col.HeaderText = "order";
       order_col.SortExpression = "order";

       gw_tipi.Columns.Add(order_col);
 }
```

All this code works fine but doesn't fire RowCommand from GridView when clicked on the ImageButton

EDIT:
I call the procedure in SelectedIndexChanged event of a DropDownList
        ddl_tipi_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender , System.EventArgs e)
        {
              inizializza_gw_tipi();
              gw_tipi.DataBind();
        }

```
    Protected Sub inizializza_gw_tipi()
       Using cn As New SqlConnection(shared_foos.connectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT nome_tabella, nome_campo_id, nome_campo_nome, nome_campo_descrizione, has_order FROM maschere_tipi WHERE id = @id", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", IIf(Session("sel_val") Is Nothing, "", Session("sel_val")))
            cn.Open()
            Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            rdr.Read()
            If rdr.HasRows Then
                Dim b_crea_controllo As Boolean = True
                'controllo se mettere o no la colonna ordine
                If rdr("has_order") = True Then
                    'controllo che la colonna non sia già stata inserita, 
                    'se è già stata inserita la rimuovo e la ricreo
                    For i As Integer = 0 To gw_tipi.Columns.Count - 1
                        If gw_tipi.Columns(i).HeaderText = "ordine" Then
                            'gw_tipi.Columns.Remove(gw_tipi.Columns(i))
                            b_crea_controllo = False
                        End If
                    Next

                    If b_crea_controllo = True Then

                        Dim ordine_col As New TemplateField()
                        ordine_col.ItemTemplate = New CreateItemTemplateOrdine("lbl_ordine", "ordine", "imgbtn_up", "~/imgs/Up.gif", "meno", "ordine", "imgbtn_down", "~/imgs/Down.gif", "piu", "ordine", AddressOf ImageCommand)
                        ordine_col.HeaderText = "ordine"
                        ordine_col.SortExpression = rdr("nome_campo_nome")

                        gw_tipi.Columns.Add(ordine_col)

                    End If
                End If

                b_crea_controllo = True

                For i As Integer = 0 To gw_tipi.Columns.Count - 1
                    If gw_tipi.Columns(i).HeaderText = rdr("nome_campo_nome") Then
                        b_crea_controllo = False
                    End If
                Next

                If b_crea_controllo = True Then
                    Dim nome_col As New TemplateField()
                    nome_col.ItemTemplate = New CreateItemTemplateLabel("lbl_nome", rdr("nome_campo_nome"))
                    nome_col.HeaderText = rdr("nome_campo_nome")
                    nome_col.SortExpression = rdr("nome_campo_nome")
                    gw_tipi.Columns.Add(nome_col)
                End If

                b_crea_controllo = True

                For i As Integer = 0 To gw_tipi.Columns.Count - 1
                    If gw_tipi.Columns(i).HeaderText = rdr("nome_campo_descrizione") Then
                        b_crea_controllo = False
                    End If
                Next

                If b_crea_controllo = True Then
                    Dim descrizione_col As New TemplateField()
                    descrizione_col.ItemTemplate = New CreateItemTemplateLabel("lbl_descrizione", rdr("nome_campo_descrizione"))
                    descrizione_col.HeaderText = rdr("nome_campo_descrizione")
                    descrizione_col.SortExpression = rdr("nome_campo_descrizione")
                    gw_tipi.Columns.Add(descrizione_col)
                End If

                Dim str_order_by As String = " ORDER BY "
                Dim str_ordine As String = ""

                If rdr("has_order") = True Then
                    str_ordine = ", ordine "
                    str_order_by &= "ordine"
                Else
                    str_order_by &= rdr("nome_campo_nome")
                End If

                Dim sqlds_tipi As New SqlDataSource(shared_foos.connectionString, "SELECT " & rdr("nome_campo_id") & ", " & rdr("nome_campo_nome") & ", " & rdr("nome_campo_descrizione") & str_ordine & " FROM " & rdr("nome_tabella") & str_order_by)

                gw_tipi.DataSource = sqlds_tipi

            End If
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your code as is and tested. there is no errors on this code. Also the row command is triggered properly. I presume the problem is with eventbinding of the dynamic gridview you created.

For the row command to be triggered the gridview has to be created on every postback. and the event should be bound.

The Code you provided is not exactly what i needed. It doesn't have the initialization of the grid view.

The following should give you some insight.

```
GridView GV = new GridView(); //Make sure to create the grid view on every postback and populate it. Alternatively (i dont know if its a good practice.) you can store a reference of gridview in session.
GV.RowCommand += new GridViewCommandEventHandler(GV_RowCommand); //bind the row command event. this should solve the problem.
```

The server doesnt keep track of dynamically created controls. So when the post back occurs the gridview control does not exist. and thus no event can be triggered.

Comment: @SimoneFoschi : Is the gridview created dynamically or populated dynamically? because in your selected index change event there is not initialization of grid view. in which case may be the only thing you are missing is **OnRowCommand="rowcommandfunction"** on the aspx page.

Comment: Resolved, i put the inizialization code in the page_load event and it fires the rowcommand as expected

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - but my problem was in the Master Page where EnableViewState="false". 
The onrowcommand worked fine, after I set he Master page to use EnableViewState="true".